# Assigning a Static Class to a Local Variable

Tags: php, oop, static, static-members

So, in PHP, I know that static classes exist in the Global namespace, and thus cause overhead when having to call them.

But what happens when you assign a local class variable, or just a local variable, to that static class? Is the overhead of the Global reference removed?

In my specific case, I'm using a static singleton.

```
class Registry {

     public static $user;
     public static $DB;
     public static $config;
     public static $user_data;
     private static $initialized = FALSE;

     public static function init($config) {
          if (!registry::$initialized) {
               registry::$config = $config;
               registry::$DB = new db($config['mysql']);
               registry::$user = new user();
               registry::$initialized = TRUE;
          } else {
               throw new Exception('Registry has already been initialized.');
          }
     }
}
```

Now, to make the question clearer, would it be beneficial to map the Registry in another class to a class variable/local variable for successive function calls?

```
class SomethingSomethingDarkSide {

     private $registry;
     private $db;
     private $config;

     public function __construct() {
          $this->registry = Registry;
          $this->db = Registry::$db;
          $this->config = Registry::$config;
     }
}
```

Since the static members are now assigned to a class variable after it's been initialized, would calling successive methods that utilize those class variables remove the overhead of the Global namespace that persist with static members?

**EDIT: Please remove the idea of Singleton in this case. The question is more about whether we have to look up `Registry` each time after its been referenced to a variable.**

IE:

```
$registry = Registry;
$registry::doSomething();
$registry::doSomething2();
$registry::doSomething3();
```

vs.

```
Registry::doSomething();
Registry::doSomething2();
Registry::doSomething3();
```

OR:

```
class Test {
      public static function sayHi() {
          echo 'Hi';
      }
}

$test = Test;

echo $test::sayHi(); // This being done multiple times versus
echo Test::sayHi(); // That being done multiple times
```

Comment: `and thus cause overhead when having to call them.` Not really overhead, the issue with using statics is nothing to do with overhead

Comment: But doesn't having to access the Global Namespace itself constantly add overhead? Let me edit to add some examples.

Comment: `$registry::doSomething();` --- why do you want a static method call when you already have an instance?

Comment: Sorry it's 2:30 AM here, fixed. Thanks.

Comment: "I know that static classes exist in the Global namespace, and thus cause overhead when having to call them." --- that's not true. As soon as the question starts with a false statement, everything in it makes not much sense, doesn't it? (upvoted to get 0 balance back, since it still doesn't deserve punishment)

Comment: I don't get your point here. If you're Registry class use the singleton pattern, then you get an instance of it at some point. From then, you're using that instance and not the static methods: `$registry = Registry::init($config); $registry->doThing();`. I think your problem is just that your singleton pattern is not correctly implemented

Comment: @pomeh The point is to have static access to a Registry that has been initialized once, and have subsequent file be able to access that Registry without being explicitly passed the Registry.

Comment: @Awesomesauce: what if you inject your dependencies explicitly instead?

Comment: @zerkms I've been sifting through the docs for a while but I can't find any leads. If a file has been included once (the registry) and initialized through `Registry::init($config)` then in what namespace does the registry exist in to subsequent classes who have not been explicitly passed an instance, because there _does not exist an instance_ since it was initialized through static means?

Comment: `without being explicitly passed the Registry` can you explain that ?

Comment: @pomeh After reading through, I believe to make the question more relevant would be to remove the idea that it is a singleton to get back to my original question. The Registry is a singleton in the sense that it's data must be initialized once, and only once, and all other references to it must be in static reference only.

Comment: Ok I understand your problem now. You can improve the question. But why `all other references to it must be in static reference only` ? Is it a constraint you have ? In what use case does this make sense ? I think you're over-complicating thing here, so it's important for us to understand **what** you want to achieve and **why* you wan this, maybe a simpler answer can be found (or maybe not!)

Comment: Your singleton implementation does make sense (or more sense). But I guess I am asking a question related to the language rather than the actual code, since it's not a constraint, as I could easily replace my `$db = Registry::$db;` with `$registry = Registry::getInstance(); $db = $registry->db;`. Calling data statically through `Registry` has to find `Registry` in the namespace no? So then does assigning `$registry = Registry;` remove having to do that in subsequent calls through `$registry` rather than `Registry`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your initial problem is that your Singleton implementation is not correct. Look at this code instead:

```
class Registry {

    private static $instance = null;

    private $user;
    private $DB;
    private $config;
    private $user_data;

    public static function getInstance($config) {
        if (self::$instance === null)
        {
            self::$instance = new self($config);
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    private function __construct($config) {
        $this->$config = $config;
        $this->$DB = new db($config['mysql']);
        $this->$user = new user();
    }

    public function doThing() {
    }

}

$registry = Registry::getInstance($config);
$registry->doThing();
```

Since the constructor is private, the only way to get a new instance of `Registry` class is to use the public static method `getInstance`.
From then, you have a `$registry` variable which points to an instance of the `Registry` class (if it's not what you want then I don't understand why you are using the Singleton pattern...)

I think that's pretty close to want you want:

```
$registry = Registry;
$registry->doSomething();
$registry->doSomething2();
$registry->doSomething3();
```

Comment: I understand that my explanation is confusing as I have always lacked colleagues to discuss these topics with. I believe the fact that we are discussing the singleton implementation is not relevant to the question. What I'm trying to say is that if we assign `$registry = Registry`, do calls through `$registry` now avoid going through the namespace to resolve `Registry`? I'm very sorry if I'm not very clear.

Comment: I think you already know that `$registry = Registry` is not a valid PHP instruction (that's why you're asking!). But I get what you want, & I can't think of any solution to do it, so I'll let other users help you in a better way than me. However, I still think that you **may** have a conception instead of a PHP problem: if I summarize, you want a **static class** Registry to have **instance variable initialized only once** and call that class in a static way in all of your code. IMHO, you're over-complicating things and I can't think of any valid use case for it, but I may be wrong about this

Comment: The thing is though that `$registry = Registry;` IS a valid PHP instruction in the sense that for some reason it works. If you run my last last example that I edited in, it works. Yes, you could say this is more conceptual than a real use case.

Comment: You're right, it's valid from PHP 5.3 to 5.6 and PHP 7, but it does trigger a notice `Notice: Use of undefined constant XXX - assumed 'XXX'` (see http://3v4l.org/FvnPH). So if it's working, what's your problem then ? I though I understood it, but no. In any case, I don't think this will really answer your problem because instead of using `Registry` everywhere you'll use `$registry`, and I still see this as a wrong conception problem

Comment: So then what do you believe is a better solution?  Singleton or completely static?

Comment: Both have serious caveats: with singleton it's hard to test and to write unit test, and with both singleton and static "class" it's hard to extend it (have derived class for example). I see static methods as "utility methods": they don't rely on anything else than theirs parameters and other methods to work => this means 1000 calls to the same static method will always returns the same result. So, since you need to save and share a state between static methods calls, I think singleton would be more appropriate here. But I wait for someone to find a solution (if any) to your initial problem.